# What is wrong with my python denary to binary program?

Tags: python

i am currently creating a denary to binary program using python and i have no idea why it is not working, if someone could help me and fix my code it would be greatly appreciated.

```
answer = []
number = 0

denaryNumber = int(input("Type the number you would like to be put in binary (LIMIT IS 255)"))
binary = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]

for x in range (0,8):
    if denaryNumber >= binary[number]:
        subtraction = binary[number] - (denaryNumber)
        answer.append (1)
        number += 1
    else:
        answer.append (0)
        number += 1
print (answer)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Comment: why are you not using a bin() built in function to convert to binary?

Comment: because i want to do it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because of the following line:

```
subtraction = binary[number] - (denaryNumber)
```

You are subtracting from an index of `binary` that will never be used again, and then assigning it to a variable that is never used. What you intend to do is this:

```
denaryNumber -= binary[number]
```

Comment: ohh yes you are right i feel so dumb thats a much simpler solution thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = []

number = 0    #what is this number for when you have the same counter in x

denaryNumber = int(input("Type the number you would like to be put in binary (LIMIT IS 255)"))

binary = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]

for x in range (0,8): #x is being updated each time the loop goes, so it's 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, just like number so number is useless

 if denaryNumber >= binary[number]:  #wrong indentation

    subtraction = binary[number] - (denaryNumber)   # you want denaryNumber - binary[x] or you will get a negative number and that's why it's not workting

   answer.append (1)      #wrong indentation  and what is 'append (1)'. why is there a space? function calls have no space between the '()'

    number += 1

    else:                 #wrong indentation
        answer.append (0) #function calls have no space between the function name and the parameter brakets 
        number += 1

print (answer)
```

Read what I put in as the comment for your code see what's wrong. The final answer should look like this:

```
answer = []
denaryNumber = int(input("Type the number you would like to be put in binary (LIMIT IS 255)"))
binary = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]

for x in range(0,8):
    if denaryNumber >= binary[x]:
        denaryNumber = denaryNumber - binary[x]
        answer.append(1)
    else:
        answer.append(0)

print(answer)
```

Some key points to note if you aren't reading the comments, indentation matters a lot in python. function calls don't have a space between their name and the `()`. Loops in python are basically `for each` loops, they will `iterate` through the `iterable` object. In this case `range()` is the iterable object and x will be your counter from 0-7.

As a side note, I know this is a homework question, but there are built in functions to do what you want to do, which you may not be able to use but it's good to know for future references. `bin()` converts a number into a binary string:

```
denaryNumber = int(input("Type the number you would like to be put in binary (LIMIT IS 255)"))
print(bin(denaryNumber))
```

If you need your output to be the same you can:

```
denaryNumber = int(input("Type the number you would like to be put in binary (LIMIT IS 255)"))
print([int(x) for x in bin(denaryNumber)[2:]])
```